# cant attach unity debugger to ios device

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, debugging, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to get my app that's being ran on an iOS device, attached to the unity debugger so I can put in breakpoints to help figure out an iOS specific issue.  Here is everything I've been experiencing and verified.

- I've tried doing the unity attachment on both MonoDevelop and Visual Studios.  On both of these I can see my device and the app in the attachment list.
- In Visual Studios I select to attach to my device and nothing happens.  It does work correctly when i select the editor.
- In Monodevelop it just spits back it couldn't connect to debugger.
- I've verified they are on the same network, Script Debugging is checked, Editor attaching is checked.

Not sure what I'm missing here to get it to link to the device.  Any help is appreciated.

***UPDATE***

After the comments about switching to mono for the builds.  Im now hitting another snag.  In xcode im getting the following error.

```
ld: Unable to insert branch island. No insertion point available. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What unity version?

Comment: did you remember to select "development build" (in build options, near where you click build). that's an annoying gotchya!

Comment: @Rob Unity Version 5.3.5p5

Comment: @JoeBlow Yes Development Build is checked

Comment: Are you compiling with IL2CPP or Mono? Check the player settings for iOS. You cannot script debug if you're using IL2CPP

Comment: @Rob its set to IL2CPP right now, let me set it to mono and try that.

Comment: Be warned, you cannot release using Mono as the scripting backend. You must use IL2CPP so ensure you test properly on IL2CPP aswell before release. More info: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-64bit.html

Comment: @Rob added update, as a result of your suggestion.

Comment: @WilliamMcCarty you must stop xcode and run the app manually then attach the unity debugger.

Comment: @Rob I can't even get a build on my device due to the error in x code I posted in my updated.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to make a little assumption here that you're using the scripting backend IL2CPP (check iOS player settings)

You cannot use script debugging when compiling using IL2CPP.
You can change to Mono in the player settings. This will allow you to use  script debugging.

NOTE: you cannot release to iOS with Mono, you MUST use IL2CPP so ensure you test your app thoroughly using IL2CPP

More information can be found here on the [Unity 64Bit iPhone notes](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/iphone-64bit.html)

Comment: My device is on iOS 11 which does not support 32 bits apps and require IL2CPP to compile in 64bits. Does that mean it is the end of debugging scripts on iOS?

Comment: When I originally answered in 2016, yes debugging of IL2CPP was not supported, however I'd like to think that's changed over the last year, however I don't know the current state of this sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It might be beneficial to debug the *generated* C++ code created by IL2CPP on the device as well. You can do that with Xcode. See the example in this blog post: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/20/il2cpp-internals-debugging-tips-for-generated-code/

Often this is easier than debugging the managed code with the Mono scripting backend, because the iOS debugger in Unity with Mono can be a bit flaky.

Comment: Urgh the flakiness is so annoying.